# Building a complex MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with 2 tables, **Events** and **Dates**, both linked with a *one-to-many* relationship, so *1 event can take place along many dates*:

- **Events table**: *eventId*, name, place,...
- **Dates table**: dateId, *eventId*, date,...

Well, I need to select "*every field in the events table, filtered by **event.place**, and one additional field containing the comma-separated list of dates (dates.date) of that specific event...*"

I have no suggestions so far.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: School work? Please add table definitions, sample data and expected result - and show us your current query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are looking for group_concat

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html

```
select events.id, group_concat(dates.date) 
from events 
inner join dates on events.id=dates.event_id
where yourcondition
group by events.id
```